# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 texture appears completely black

Tags: android, opengl-es, rendering, textures

I am having problems rendering textures loaded from the assets folder. If I do exactly the same procedure loading the same texture from the resources folder, everything works fine. Also the image from the assets seems to be loading correctly as when I get the width and height property from the bitmap object, these correspond with the dimensions of the file on disk. However attempting to render the texture results in plain black.

```
// [...]
int [] tmpId = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, tmpId, 0);
int id = tmpId[0];
InputStream in = null;
try {
   in = context.getAssets().open(resource);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
bitmap.recycle();
```

Am I missing something, are there rules which apply to assets which are different from resources? I can´t seem to figure out why this isn´t working.

The image is 512x512 png format with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure as You didn't present the rest of the code, but basing on what You've shown it seems that You're unbinding the texture, which You want to draw, through glBindTexture call with the last parameter equal 0.